# Magento always requires 'bcmath' but it is already installed

Tags: magento-2.0

I've already installed php7.0-bcmath but my Magento application still doesn't recognize it.

Inside my `php -i` bcmath has this settings

```
bcmath

BCMath support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
bcmath.scale => 0 => 0
```

Should I set the .scale to 1? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 thoughts for you:

- you may verify the php version used by your webserver is also 7.0
- You may want to restart the web server?

Answer (score 0):

PHP can have different configuration for command line (CLI) versus web server. You need to ensure `bcmath` is enabled on both.

You can run `php -i` (CLI) and `phpinfo()` (web) to see PHP's configuration, and the exact `.ini` config files it is processing for each.

Comment: I couldn't fix that. I formatted my pc and the setup of Magento went well. Thanks for the answers anyway. Have a good life.